# Converting NeDB find() results to observable

Tags: javascript, observable, nedb

The question is simple: how do I make method `find()` return an Observable with found docs inside of it?

If I use promises, everything works fine.

```
getData(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.db.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(docs);
  });
})
}
```

But, if I try to use observables to solve this problem like this:

```
  getDataObs() {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      this.db.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) subscriber.error(err);
        subscriber.next(docs);
      });
    })
  }
```

the results the subscriber gets are undefined.

I came across a method of creating observables, `bindCallback()` that should resolve this issue, since it accepts a callback and returns an observable. But I wasn't able to use it properly. I really need some help in understanding this, since I'm not experienced with reactive programming and it all seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  getData(){
    var arr =[];
    return this.getDataObs().subscribe(rs=>{
      if(rs && rs.length>0) arr = rs;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when looking for a way to use Nedb + Observables...

I suggest to use [**`bindNodeCallback()`**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) instead, assuming `this.db` is the result of Nedb's Datastore constructor:

```
getDataObs() {
   var boundFind = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.db.find).bind(this.db);
   return boundFind({}); // will emit docs, if an error occurs it will fail properly
}
```